# Call Custom Constructor On Template Typename

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, polymorphism, constructor-overloading

Let's say I have the following code:

```
Class A
{
public:
    A(B* b)
      : m_B(*b)
    {}

    //Default constructor won't work as it needs to initialize "m_B"
    
private:
    B& m_B;
};
```

And then I have a class B:

```
class B
{
public:
    //check that typename is a derivative of A
    template<typename T>
    AddInstance()
    {
        T* instance = new T(this);
        m_Instances.emplace_back(instance);
    }

private:
    std::vector<A*> m_Instances;
};
```

In this case, I have to construct class A in `AddInstance` with a constructor which can initialize `m_B`. Yet when I do this (and I make sure typename derives from A using the following concept:
`template<typename T> concept Derivative = std::is_base_of<A, T>::value;`) I'm unable to initialize the typename variable with anything but the default constructor. If I know for sure that typename inherits from A, is there a way to initialize it through an overloaded constructor?

**Note:** In my project class A would be an abstract class, and so the typename would be a specialized derivative of A which I would emplace into the vector

**Edit**
So I figured out my issue. I assumed that an inheriting class would be able to call a constructor from its base class. Rather the deriving class needs to create its own constructor that initializes its base class. The whole idea I'm going for with my project is that one should do as little as possible to create a new deriving class, as so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
AddInstance<Specialization>();

//In AddInstance:
{
    A* instance = new A(this);
    m_Instances.emplace_back(static_cast<Specialization*>(instance));
}
```

So hypothetically I should be able to construct a new class with A's constructor and then cast it into the desired specialization. Although when I actually do this I just execute A's methods rather than the Specialization's overrides

Comment: You have several problems in your code, but I don't think you need a template parameter at all here: https://godbolt.org/z/sdzY5MqYY

Comment: cannot reproduce: for me works with both `template <Derivative T>` and `template <typename T> void AddInstance() requires Derivative<T>`

Comment: I read up on emplace_back a bit, and I understand what you mean about constructing a new entry without the typename initialization. The problem is that in my actual project I emplace derivatives of class A, where A is an Abstract Class. So I need to specialize the entry using the specified typename and then emplace it

Comment: Can you expand this to a [mcve], and provide the exact error messages?

Comment: One problem I see is that `m_Instances` can only hold `A` objects, not classes derived from it.

Comment: A vector of type A can accept a class that inherits from A as an entry

Comment: My bad though, the Vector has to be of type A*, not A for polymorphism to work correctly, I'll fix that